# Diesel with custom wrapper types

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have custom types that serve as a wrapper of other types than can be safely used in Diesel:

```
use uuid::Uuid;

pub schema Post {
  id: PostId,
  title: String,
  body: String
}

pub schema PostId {value: Uuid}
```

I can't use these custom wrappers with Diesel. The error message I get is the following:

```
#[derive(Insertable)]
the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `models::PostId`
```

I've tried to look for examples on converting custom types and so far the two approaches I've seen are to either implement the `AsExpression` trait or the `FromSql` and `ToSql` traits, but the examples I've seen so far are for enum types and I can't infer what's the difference between the two approaches other than the former seems to be an older way of doing it, nor what the expected implementation of those traits are.

Comment: Custom types in diesel (and other rust orms I tried) is quite painful unfortunately. I recently wrote a [post](https://kitsu.me/posts/2020_05_24_custom_types_in_diesel) for a simpler case, hope it can help.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Shepmaster! I've added some extra info that might explain the issue, but thanks to the answer from Weiznich I finally solved the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Based on weiznich's answer, I came up with the following solution for serializand/deserializing my custom wrapper type:

```
use uuid::Uuid;
use super::schema::posts;
use diesel::serialize::{self, IsNull, Output, ToSql};
use std::io::Write;
use diesel::deserialize::{self, FromSql};
use diesel::backend::Backend;
use diesel::pg::Pg;

#[derive(Queryable, Debug)]
pub struct Post {
    pub id: PostId,
    pub body: String,
    pub title: String
}

#[derive(Insertable)]
#[table_name="posts"]
pub struct NewPost<'a> {
    pub id: PostId,
    pub body: &'a str,
    pub title: &'a str
}

#[derive(AsExpression, FromSqlRow, Debug)]
#[sql_type = "diesel::sql_types::Uuid"]
pub struct PostId{pub value: Uuid}

impl<DB: Backend<RawValue=[u8]>> FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, DB> for PostId {
  fn from_sql(bytes: Option<&DB::RawValue>) -> deserialize::Result<Self> {
    <uuid::Uuid as FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, Pg>>::from_sql(bytes).map(|value| PostId{ value })
  }
}

impl ToSql<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, Pg> for PostId {
  fn to_sql<W: Write>(&self, out: &mut Output<W, Pg>) -> serialize::Result {
    <uuid::Uuid as ToSql<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, Pg>>::to_sql(&self.value, out)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement those three mentioned traits + a few more. `AsExpression` + `FromSqlRow` are implemented by the corresponding derives. `FromSql` and `ToSql` require a manual impl.

```rust
use diesel::deserialize::{self, FromSql};
use diesel::pg::Pg;
use diesel::serialize::{self, ToSql};
use std::io::Write;

#[derive(AsExpression, FromSqlRow)]
#[sql_type = "diesel::sql_types::Uuid"]
pub schema PostId {
    value: uuid::Uuid,
}

impl FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, Pg> for PostId {
    fn from_sql(bytes: Option<&DB::RawValue>) -> deserialize::Result<Self> {
        <uuid::Uuid as FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, Pg>>::from_sql(bytes)
            .map(|value| PostId { value })
    }
}

impl ToSql<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, Pg> for PostId {
    fn to_sql<W: Write>(&self, out: &mut Output<W, DB>) -> serialize::Result {
        <uuid::Uuid as ToSql<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, Pg>>::to_sql(&self.0, out)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @weiznich! I had to modify it just a bit, but all the credits go to you!